# Remove and add class not working in FF

Tags: jquery

```
$('#resTable .wsButton').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("btPrimary")) {
        $(this).removeAttr("href");
        $(this).removeClass("btPrimary");
        $(this).addClass("btPrimaryPrint");
    }
});
```

this code is workng in IE but not in FF.
m i doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you tell if it's working or not?

Comment: It works for me. Can I see your HTML code? http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/mSNjw/1/

Comment: @Jon: m checking the class in IE dev tool bar for IE and Firebug for FF. In IE its showing btPrimaryPrint but in FF its not changing. @YNhat: I hv pasted the code above. Only this much code is written in doc.ready function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view :

http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/CURCH/

http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/CURCH/1/

It's working on ie, ff and other browsers

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

it should work

Comment: its already in $(document).ready(function(){. Working in IE but nt in FF

Answer (score 0):

just insert a comma between selector.

```
$('#resTable, .wsButton').each
```

Comment: @rohit before if statement, try an alert statement to debug, may be your `if` statement is always false

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar error but it get resolved when I kept the event handler  method outside the (document).ready method since it was loading on page reload and not on that particular event.
I hope I am clear

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
//your code
```

Answer (score -1):

Dude just replace your first line with :

```
$('#resTable, .wsButton').each(function ()
```